# Sectional Curvature of Paraboloid

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I seem to have made a mistake while doing the simple exercises of calculating 2D sectional curvature of paraboloid $z=\frac a2 (x^2+y^2)$. I used polar coordinates to do this; $(r,\theta)=(\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\arctan\frac xy)$.

To calculate the sectional curvature, the connection coefficients were first calculated, and my calculation of the connection coefficients were identical to one I found on the web: http://mathserver.neu.edu/~bratus/diffgeom/sol3/sol3.htm (Ctrl+F "formula for the curvature tensor")

$\Gamma^1_{11}=\frac{a^2r}{1+a^2r}, \Gamma^2_{12}=\Gamma^2_{21}=\frac 1r, \Gamma^1_{22}=\frac{-r}{1+a^2r}$, and the rest are $0$.

And then I proceeded to calculate the curvature tensor, which gave me a wrong result! *I think that the mistake I made is probably that* $\nabla_1(\Gamma^1_{22} e_1) = \Gamma^1_{22,1} e_1 + \Gamma^1_{22}\nabla _1 e_1 = \Gamma^1_{22,1} + \Gamma^1_{22} \Gamma^1_{11} e_1 + \Gamma^1_{22} \Gamma^2_{22} e_2$, but I can't find any reason why this should be wrong though. The full calculation I did and the comparison with the solution is given below:

$R(e_1,e_2)e_2 = \nabla_1\nabla_2 e_2 - \nabla_2 \nabla_1 e_2 
\\= \nabla_1(\Gamma^1_{22} e_1 + \Gamma^2_{22}e_2) - \nabla_2(\Gamma^1_{12}e_1 + \Gamma^2_{12}e_2) 
\\= \nabla_1(\Gamma^1_{22}e_1) - \nabla_2(\Gamma^2_{12}e_2)\text{ (since $\Gamma^2_{22}=\Gamma^1_{12}=0$.)} \\= \Gamma^1_{22,1} e_1 + \Gamma^1_{22} \nabla_1 e_1 - \Gamma^2_{12,2}e_2 - \Gamma^2_{12} \nabla_2 e_2\\
=\Gamma^1_{22,1} e_1 + \Gamma^1_{22} (\Gamma^1_{11} e_1 + \Gamma^2_{11} e_2) - \Gamma^2_{12,2} e_2 - \Gamma^2_{12} (\Gamma^1_{22} e_1 + \Gamma^2_{22} e_2)$

and therefore

$R^2_{212}=d\theta(R(e_1,e_2)e_2) = \Gamma^1_{22}\Gamma^2_{11} - \Gamma^2_{12,2} - \Gamma^2_{12}\Gamma^2_{22} = 0 - \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(\frac 1r) + 0 = 0$

However, thet solution says that $R^2_{212} = \frac 1{r^2}$. I have checked over this calculation multiple times and I can't find any problem. Can someone help me out, please?

**Appended:** I append some further (probably flawed) calculation results of mine:

$R^1_{212}
\\=dr(R(e_1,e_2)e_2)
\\=dr(\Gamma^1_{22,1} e_1 + \Gamma^1_{22} (\Gamma^1_{11} e_1 + \Gamma^2_{11} e_2) - \Gamma^2_{12,2} e_2 - \Gamma^2_{12} (\Gamma^1_{22} e_1 + \Gamma^2_{22} e_2))
\\=\Gamma^1_{22,1} + \Gamma^1_{22}\Gamma^1_{11} - \Gamma^2_{12}\Gamma^1_{22}
\\=\frac{-(1+a^2r^2)+r\cdot 2a^2 r}{(1+a^2r^2)^2} - \frac{a^2r^2}{(1+a^2r^2)^2} - \frac{-1}{(1+a^2r^2)^2}
\\=\frac{-1-a^2r^2+2a^2r^2 - a^2r^2 + 1}{(1+a^2r^2)^2}
\\=0$

and therefore, sectional curvature is

$K(e_1,e_2)
\\=\frac{\langle R(e_1,e_2)e_2,e_1\rangle}{|e_1|^2|e_2|^2-\langle e_1,e_2 \rangle^2}
\\=g_{11} R^1_{212}/(r^2(1+a^2r^2))
\\=(1+a^2r^2)\cdot 0 / (r^2(1+a^2r^2))=0$

Comment: Can you define your $d\theta (R(e_1, e_2), e_2)$?

Comment: Firstly I accidentally put a comma there; it should have been $d\theta(R(e_1,e_2)e_2)$ instead.

Also, pardon my shorthands; $e_1, e_2$ each represents $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$, the basis vectors. Thus $d\theta$ is simply the dual basis vector $e_2^*$, which takes all the coefficients of $e_2$ from the curvature tensor $R(e_1, e_2)e_2$.

Comment: Your solution has a typo. 

Your coordinate system is orthogonal. So $R^2_{212} \propto R_{2212} = 0$, the equality by the elementary symmetry properties of the Riemann curvature tensor.

Comment: Might be that's also why you got zero. Probably you want to calculate $dr (R(e_1, e_2) e_2)$?

Comment: Looking at the link you posted, note that due to the coordinates being orthogonal, the $R^{2}_{212}$ component contributes exactly nil to the sectional curvature $R_{1212}$ (because $g_{12} = 0$). So even with the incorrect computation for the components of the Riemann curvature tensor, the sectional curvature value obtained in the "solutions" is actually correct. (My personal paranoia makes me wonder if this is an easter egg put in by an instructor to detect students who cheat...)

Comment: @John I tried that too and got zero as well. I will write out what I got above.

Comment: @WillieWong thanks for your attention! But even when I calculated the other supposed non-zero contributer $R^1_{212}$ I got zero again. I will write out what I got above.

Comment: There's also a typo in the linked "solution" for $\Gamma^1_{11}$ and $\Gamma^1_{22}$. The denominator should have $1+a^2 r^2$ and not $1 + a^2 r$ as written.

Comment: And looking at it slightly more carefully, the expression for $R_{1212}$ is also wrong. So is his computation of $g$. Manifestly based on the $g_{11}$ and $g_{22}$ he showed, $g \neq r^2$. I think you should just avoid using that particular website altogether, especially considering that the [correct answer can be found on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraboloid#Curvature).

Comment: However at any case my flawed calculation yields that the curvature is $0$ (refer to the appended calculations) which is wrong! (paraboloid has positive curavture; everyone knows that). I wonder what went wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your revised question:

$$ \Gamma^1_{22} \Gamma^2_{12} = \frac{-r}{1 + a^2 r^2} \frac{1}{r} = - \frac{1}{1+a^2 r^2}. $$

In your computations you wrote instead

$$ \Gamma^1_{22} \Gamma^2_{12} "=" - \frac{1}{(1+a^2 r^2)^2}$$

Fixing that you should get

$$ R^1_{212} = \frac{a^2 r^2}{(1 + a^2 r^2)^2} $$

So that

$$ R_{1212} = g_{11} R^1_{212} = \frac{a^2 r^2}{1 + a^2 r^2} $$

So that

$$ K = R_{1212} / g = \frac{a^2}{(1+ a^2 r^2)^2} $$

Comment: thanks a lot for sorting out the issue. I actually have resolved it myself after few more pages of computation, and the central issue has been that I forgot to multiply $g_{11}$ in lowering the index. I will read what you have wrote here tomorrow, since I am in such a rush right now. But thanks again anyway!